# Linear reformulation or approximation of a quadratic inequality set

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, quadratic-forms, matrix-decomposition, quadratic-programming

Based on the useful comments I reformulated my problem - hopefully it's more clear now.

Let $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ be symmetric positive-semidefinite matrices, $x  \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $||\cdot||^2$ the quadratic $l_2$-Norm.

Now I'm interested in those $x$, for which $||Ax||^2 \leq ||Bx||^2$. However, I'm not looking for the solution of this quadratic problem per se, but I need to characterize the set of $x$, for which $||Ax||^2 \leq ||Bx||^2$ holds, in terms of linear constraints, i.e. I'm looking for $G \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times d}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^k$, such that the set $$\lbrace x: G x \leq b \rbrace$$ is equal to or an approximation of the set $$\lbrace x: ||Ax||^2 \leq ||Bx||^2 \rbrace.$$ $k$ (the number of linear constraints / number of rows of $G$) may be arbitrary.

In geometrical terms (if I'm not mistaken), the solution of my initial problem is an intersection of ellipsoids, which I'm trying to characterize via a polyhedron.

Some additional information (not sure if these are helpful in any way):

- $Q := A^T A - B^T B$ is indefinite, but the trace of $Q$ is equal to zero (I tried to use this in combination with diagonalization of $A$ and $B$, which gives a quadratic inequality with a sum constraint for the eigenvalues - but how to procede from there?).
- $A^T A$ and $B^T B$ are not simultaneously diagonalizable

Any thoughts? Are there any established procedures for this kind of approximation?

Comment: What does it mean for $Bx\ge 0$?

Comment: What does it mean for a vector to be non-negative?

Comment: and how should $A$ and $B$ actually be connected or do you say, there shouldn't be any?

Comment: @CameronWilliams : Sorry, didn't get your hint about my sloppy notation at first... I hope my first edit clarifies this now

Comment: If $A=gg^T$, the condition $x^TAx\ge0$ is empty hence one should use $B=0$, not the $B$ you suggest. In general, not much can be done since the condition $x^TAx\ge0$ is invariant by the transformation $x\to-x$ while the condition $Bx\ge0$ is not.

Comment: @Did : You are right. I've to be more precisely about $A$ or $A_1$ and $A_2$. I will reformulate my example and/or question. Thanks guys!